# Valor Nulo exibindo zero MS Access

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Eu preciso setar um campo no Access para Null, através de SQL, porém após setar este campo, ele fica com o valor Zero e não Null. Devido a uma regra de negócio, eu preciso que este campo fique NULO e não Zero. O campo é numérico.

Comment: Você definiu esse campo de que forma? `UPDATE tabela SET campo = NULL WHERE id = xx`?

Comment: Isso mesmo.....

Comment: Como você criou esse campo? Põe o `DDL` aí

Answer (score 1):

Esta configuração deve funcionar (configuração por defeito):

[image: Propriedades do Campo]

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente o Access some com os NULL quando se usa dentro de um SUM;
Outra possibilidade é que você pode ter colocado um DEFAULT 0 no seu campo;

Há uma resposta sobre algo similar neste [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother/zero-vs-null-plus-default-value-property/e3755c40-9ac3-4af1-8bc3-366f9ea7c728).